# Remove a parameter from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameter-passing, link-to

I have a link_to method in my Rails app:

```
link_to t('edit'), edit_building_path(@building, :hidden_action => params[:action])
```

**How do I remove hidden_action from url?**

Currently url looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/buildings/2/edit?hidden_action=new
```

My issue is that I need to know from which page user is accessing this link_to.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. If you don't want the `hidden_action` param in the URL, don't append it as parameter in the method call.

Comment: I need a hidden_action parameter for the next use in controller

Comment: Then pass it via session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails helper, it depends on you

```
def edit_the_building_url(building, you_want_the_params_or_not)
  if you_want_the_params_or_not
    edit_building_path(building, :hidden_action => params[:action])
  else
    edit_building_path(building)
  end
end
```

then in your controller

```
link_to t('edit'), edit_the_building_url(@building, true)
```

or

```
link_to t('edit'), edit_the_building_url(@building, false)
```

**if above doesn't profit you, just**

```
url = url.chomp("?hidden_action=#{params[:action]}")
```